# Keep first record in group and populate rest with Null/0 in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have the following table in my database:

```
       date sales
1  2010-12-13    10
2  2010-12-13    10
3  2010-12-13    10
4  2010-12-13    10
5  2010-12-13    10
6  2010-12-14    20
7  2010-12-14    20
8  2010-12-14    20
9  2010-12-14    20
10 2010-12-14    20
```

Is there a way to attain the first record only and populate the rest with NULL or 0 for the remainder of the group? AS the grouping will be done by date and sales:

For example the intended output is:

```
         date sales
1  2010-12-13    10
2  2010-12-13    0
3  2010-12-13    0
4  2010-12-13    0
5  2010-12-13    0
6  2010-12-14    20
7  2010-12-14    0
8  2010-12-14    0
9  2010-12-14    0
10 2010-12-14    0
```

So essentially to keep the first record but make the rest of the records in the group be 0 (maybe Null if that is quicker/easier)

The closest i have got to solving this is attaining just the first record through an inner join - but I think a partition over may solve it - just stuck at the moment!

Any help appreciated!

Using SQLite - but also GCP (SQL) is accesible to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work in SQLite:

```
CASE WHEN id = MIN(id) OVER(PARTITION BY date) THEN sales ELSE 0 END as sales
```

If it doesn't you can prepare a subquery that has only the min ID per date and join it in:

```
SELECT
   CASE WHEN y.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE sales END as sales
FROM
  x
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT MIN(id) as id FROM x GROUP BY date) y ON x.id= y.id
```

Comment: Yep - first solution works fine - I did however use: `select *,
           CASE WHEN rowid = MIN(rowid) OVER(PARTITION BY date) THEN sales ELSE 0 END as new_sales
          from 
           df` as Min(rowid) is native to SQLite!

Comment: Ah, i thought that 1,2,3,4.. was your incrementing ID!

Comment: Might be worth noting that ROWID in SQLite is an autoincrementing int64, but it isn't always the case that the earlier row has a lower ID. There are cases where SQLite will have to fill in ROWIDs that are of lower number than existing rows even though the row itself is later. It probably won't bother your case, however; you'll still end up with *some* row that is the MIN, even if it wasn't necessarily the earliest written row.. but you wouldnt be able to tell anyway..